# how can I reduce the tearing effect due to the angle?

Tags: modeling

as u can see on the images I have a weird render

I don't really know how to reduce this effect, I tried to add more line by subdivsion but it still there.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "tearing" effect you are talking about is appearing since the polygons of the mesh are not **shaded smooth**. There are several ways to fix it. In your case you can follow this steps:
*Select an object -> RMB(To call an object context menu) -> Shade Auto Smooth(since you seem to have a steep edge there)*

Then, if needed you can adjust the autosmooth in *Object Data Properties -> Normals Panel*.

If you are interested in scripted solution, here is the code to smooth the polygons of the mesh:

```py
import bpy

# Setting use_smooth property for each polygon in active object's mesh
for f in bpy.context.active_object.data.polygons:
    f.use_smooth = True
    
bpy.context.active_object.data.use_auto_smooth = True # Enabeling Auto Smooth
```

Documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/shading.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: that's perfect thanks